# Why does this code always print "not matched"?

Tags: c, compare, popen, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *ls = popen("tmp.sh", "r");
    char char_array[256];
    while (fgets(char_array, sizeof(char_array), ls) != 0) {
       //NOP
    }
    char *ptr_somechar = &char_array[0];
    char *pointer = "high";
    if (strcmp(pointer, ptr_somechar) == 0) 
    { 
        printf("%s\n", "match");
    } else 
    { 
        printf("%s\n", "not matched");
    }
    pclose(ls);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to compare the output with the line. `tmp.sh` returns a "high". Why does this code always print "not matched"?

Comment: Just a wild guess: Could it be that tmp.sh prints "high" including a newline (e.g. when using `echo`) ...?

Comment: Did you chmod x that shell script?

Comment: it seems the code is reading the contents of the file 'tmp.sh'.  line by line.  the strcmp() starts at the first char in the input buffer when trying to make the comparison.  it is highly probably that 'high' are not the first characters in the input buffer, of the last line read from the tmp.sh file.   Suggest using substr() (or similar function) so the whole line is searched) and search every line, not just the last line.

Comment: @user3629249 if that is happening on Linux he will get `sh: 1: tmp.sh: not found`. The first argument of popen is command. If `popen("./tmp.sh", "r")` was used and shell script is x chmoded then he will get output of script execution with \n, if script is not x chmoded it is again not found, but he doesn't use popen like that. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the string `"high"` in file is followed by a newline character and `fgets` reads that `\n` too. You need to remove that character before comparison.